# Running Out of Threads on Debian

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, bash, threadpool

I have a program that creates a specified amount of active threads on my debian machine. When I try to create anything over 100 I get an error saying "Error in creating thread" when it reaches the OS limitation and machine doesn't accept any incoming connections and when executing commands I get "-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory". Looking at the top command I see tasks are getting maxed out at 32564 and only 20% of my RAM is being utilized. I tried editing ulimit -a & -n to 500000 and -s to 81920 but still doesn't do anything. Any help is greatly appreciated/.

Comment: Why don't you increase maximum number of user processes (`ulimit -u`)?

Comment: Could be some [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) limit. Look into `/etc/security/limits.conf`etc). However creating 100 *runnable* threads is unreasonable unless you have an expensive multi-socket server.

Comment: Do you *really* need over 100 threads?  Remember that the OS still has to swap these threads with other threads.  Unless you can tell the OS to execute a thread on a separate core exclusively, it's still having to swap your threads with other processes.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my end. I increased ulimit -u & -n values to 500000. I'm trying to max out my server capabilities so I'm trying to create as many threads as possible. Right now I'm 20% utilization with RAM and 10% CPU but the OS settings seems to be the bottleneck. Once I figure how to tweak these settings I'll either scale up or down.

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, when using threads a good rule of thumb for increased performance for CPU bound processes is to use an equal number of threads as cores, except in the case of a hyper-threaded system in which case one should use twice as many cores. The other rule of thumb that can be concluded is for I/O bound processes. This rule is to quadruple the number threads per cores, except for the case of a hyper-threaded system, then one can quadruple the number of threads per core. So you probably shouldn't be making 100's of threads anyway. Just do "enough".